# Datadog APM Resource column is not giving correct values

Tags: node.js, datadog

I am facing trouble where datadog RESOURCE column is not giving the correct value as shown in the image. Really need some help here.

[image]

My assumption is that, it is happening because http tags are not appearing correctly. I think datadog itself add the http tags and it's value.
The http.path_group & http.route should have this value "/api-pim2/v1/attribute/search" but for some reason it's not coming correctly.

[image]

I am using this library [dd-trace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dd-trace) at backend. The tracers options which i provided are these

```
{"logInjection":true,"logLevel":"debug","runtimeMetrics":true,"analytics":true,"debug":true,"startupLogs":true,"tags":{"env":"dev02","region":"us-east-1","service":"fabric-gateway-pim-ecs"}}
```

The initialising code looks like this which ran at the start of my app

app/lib/tracer.js:

```
const config = require('config')
const tracerOptions = config.get('dataDog.tracer.options')
const logger = require('app/lib/logger')

const tracer = require('dd-trace').init({
  ...tracerOptions,
  enabled: true,
  logger
})

module.exports = tracer
```

I also tried to set the http.path_group & http.route tag manually but still it's not updating the values. Though i can add the new tags like http.test which has the same value which i was trying to override in http.path_group & http.route

```
const addTagsToRootSpan = tags => {
  const span = tracer.scope().active()
  if (span) {
    const root = span.context()._trace.started[0]
    for (const tag of tags) {
      root.setTag(tag.key, tag.value)
    }
    log.debug('Tags added')
  } else {
    log.debug('Trace span could not be found')
  }
}

...
const tags = [
        { key: 'http.path_group', value: request.originalUrl },
        { key: 'http.route', value: request.originalUrl },
        { key: 'http.test', value: request.originalUrl }

      addTagsToRootSpan(tags)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was requiring tracer.js file at the start of my app where server was listening.

```
require('app/lib/tracer')

app.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) {
      log.error(err)
      return err
    }
    log.info(`Your server is ready for ${config.get('stage')} on PORT ${port}!`)
  })
```

By enabling the debug option in datadog tracer init function. I can see the tracer logs and what values are passed by the library for http.route and resource.

I was confused by this line according to the [data dog tracers doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/dd_libraries/nodejs/?tab=containers#adding-the-tracer-in-code) you should init first before importing any instrumented module.

> // This line must come before importing any instrumented module.
>
> const tracer = require('dd-trace').init();

But for me http.route & resource value get correct if i initialise it on my routing file. They start giving me complete route "/api-pim2/v1/attribute/search" instead of only "/api-pim2"

routes/index.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
require('app/lib/tracer')

const attributeRouter = require('app/routes/v1/attribute')

router.use('/v1/attribute', attributeRouter)

module.exports = router
```

I am not accepting this answer yet because i am still confused where to initialise the tracer. Maybe someone can explain better. I am just writing this answer if someone else facing the issue can try this. Might just resolve their problem.

Comment: 1. you should import/require dd-trace as soon as possible
2. datadog sets resource based on router.use() or app.use() calls. So because you have `router.use('/v1/attribute', attributeRouter)` for all endpoints in attributeRouter resource will be `/v1/attribute`. Not sure if this is a feature or a bug

Comment: i usually use `http.path_group` but it's not reliable as it sometimes mistakenly replaces parts of path with `?` because it thinks that it's a parameter (like id)